# Share Photoshop license between Windows and Mac

Tags: windows, macos, adobe, photoshop

got a question regarding Adobe Photoshop CS6; can I share one license for it, originally bought for Windows, also on my Mac?

Read on Internet that Adobe allows to install Photoshop up to 2 machines (if only they are owned by the same user).

Appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing of end user software, not software development.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe does not have a license that allows you to put software on two different types of machines - the license is specific to Windows or Mac, though in the terms two Macs or two PCs are permitted if they are YOUR machines.

Adobe Creative Cloud, however, does allow two different architectures (Mac and PC) to be licensed simultaneously. Creative Cloud, however is a "rental" model, not a perpetual (full) license.